# How to create latex template like this

Tags: templates

I want to create pdf cheetsheets from latex?

How can I create like this [one](https://cheatsheet-maker.herokuapp.com/sheet/62d31381c1c62f001511c356)?

Comment: StackExchange doesn't work well with "how do I do this".  And StackExchange doesn't like links to external sources, because they can rot and the question becomes meaningless.  And we don't like clicking links to begin with.  What do you have so far?  What's giving you trouble?

Comment: Agree. // However, the colorful looks like what you want: https://de.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/cheat-sheet/page/2 . You may also want to check out this package : https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox .